# how to do complex join on same column?

Tags: sql, join, case, hiveql

I am trying to create a table using complex join among multiple tables..

[image]

using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will give following result

[image]

however, for all the rows where category is coming blank, i want to do an `SELF JOIN` on `sellerid` to get category filled

Comment: please suggest how this can be done

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: will post tables in text..

Comment: You should store catID into the sale table.

Comment: i cant change the structure of original tables...but would creating temp table help?

Comment: A bit odd table design.